# How to query xmpp archive to get latest 20 message per user

Tags: xmpp, ejabberd, ejabberd-module

If I have 20 users, each user have 100 archived messages.
How can I get the latest 20 archived messages of all 20 users in one query?

This query doesn't work that way...

```
<iq type='set' id='test1'>
  <query xmlns='urn:xmpp:mam:0'>
    <set xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/rsm'>
        <max>20</max>
        <before/>
    </set>
  </query>
</iq>
```

Answer (score 0):

XMPP does not support this kind of Query.You may need to change source code and introduce custom request to achieve this behavior.

Comment: Why xmpp is so lame, what I do now is I wrong sql query to query its mysql db.